# Casting object in generics in C# - InvalidCast Exception

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, .net

I have a generic userControl I made, that given a Type T (where T is a class), create a tree with all the types that implement T in the tree (obviously finding them with Reflection).
The tree works fine, but when I tried to implement an event that tells me that a type was selected, Im getting an InvalidCastException, or that my function doesn't work, no matter what I do.

The function is:

```
void TypeView_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
      if ((typeSelected != null) && (e.Node.Tag is T))
           typeSelected((T)e.Node.Tag)
}
```

in `e.Node.Tag` there is an object that is really of type `T`
`typeSelected` is of type `Action<T>`

so in this manner, e.Node.Tag is T is false on runtime, but is true when I set watch on it
also, if I remove the condition Im getting the exception from `(T)e.Node.Tag`, although again, the watch succeeds in casting it.

the type in runtime is `RuntimeType`....

so why is this happening, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please provide: (1) The code that shows how T is declared (2) the exact error message

Comment: I think you'll need to provide the code where you're assigning the value into the Tag property of each node.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if the type of e.Node.Tag is a derived type of T.
If this is the case, you should look into [Variants & CoVariants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386%28VS.100%29.aspx#Y404)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't assigned a value to T. You have to pass the generic assignment of T through to a method - not an event handler - in the method's signature.

```
void TypeView_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEvenArgs e)
{     
    DoWhateverAfterMouseClicked<string>(sender, e);    
}

public void DoWhateverAfterMouseClicked<T>(object sender, TreeNodeClickEventArgs e)
{    
           if ((typeSelected != null) && (e.Node.Tag is T))
                    typeSelected((T)e.Node.Tag);

}
```

Comment: T is declared on the parent class, and also, I don't see how this will help since DoWhateverAfterMouseClicked<string>(sender, e); uses the constant <string> while I need to cast to the type T...